# Configure an anti-DDOS on a server with iptables and/or VPN by using OVH's anti-DDOS

Tags: networking, iptables, ip, ddos, ovh

I am hosting my server on my computer at home and I would like to install an anti-DDOS system by using the anti-DDOS managed by OVH. I am actually redirecting my domain name to the IP of one of my OVH servers and this one redirects with iptables all traffic of specified ports to my computer at home. The problem is that every user has the IP of my OVH server, how to bypass ? I have already looked and tested solutions with other redirection and VPN but I can't find anything that solve my problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "install"?

Comment: Find a solution with iptables or a VPN or whatever to use the anti-ddos system of OVH as a meeting point between users and my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am hosting my server on my computer at home

This is already a bad idea if this is for business use. Most home networks don't have the bandwidth capability to support a business server. Not to mention, most ISPs block this type of use through their EULA.

> like to install an anti-DDOS system

You can't "install" DDOS protection, you have to build it into the environment. If you're worried about being DDOS'ed, then you should host the machine in an network which can support the bandwidth of the DDOS, with multiple tiered load-balancers and work with your ISP to black-hole routes where the DDOS is originating from.

A lot of the work done to mitigate a DDOS is done with the help of the provider to block the connections before they ever get to your server in the first place.

I would suggest looking into hosting services which provide DDOS protection. CloudFlare or Akamai are some big-name providers who can properly mitigate this kind of attack.

Comment: Thank you very much, I finally decided to use CloudFlare.